# Upload file to S3 using Elastic Beanstalk not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot application running on Elastic Beanstalk. I am trying to add a file to the S3 database. Locally everything works fine, files are stored but on the server I am getting the following error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tomcat.16714439602680400389.5000/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/upload_95b87801_b27e_4290_9b27_1b5eed71ea49_00000000.tmp (No such file or directory)

I will be grateful for any advice.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring.start</groupId>
    <artifactId>springProjekt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springProjekt</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <start.class>com.spring.start.springProjekt.SpringProjektApplication</start.class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unidata-all</id>
            <name>Unidata All</name>
            <url>https://artifacts.unidata.ucar.edu/repository/unidata-all/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!--springframework-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--servlet jstl-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--tomcat-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--mysql-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--lombok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!--gson-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--xml-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.w3c/dom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.w3c</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Amazon-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.547</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--pdf-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Netcdf-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
            <artifactId>netcdfAll</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-beta6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
            <artifactId>netcdf</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.spring.start.springProjekt.SpringProjektApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My application.propertis:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=hk2-utils.jar,javax.annotation-api.jar,javax.inject.jar,hk2-api.jar,config-types.jar,hk2-core.jar,hk2-config.jar,tiger-types.jar,validation-api.jar,jboss-logging.jar,classmate.jar,hk2-locator.jar,javassist.jar,hk2-runlevel.jar,class-model.jar,asm-all-repackaged.jar
server.port=5000
spring.profiles.active=aws_ebs

spring.datasource.url=base on S3
characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50

spring.messages.always-use-message-format=false
spring.messages.basename=messages
spring.messages.cache-duration=-1
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.com.spring.start.springProjekt=DEBUG

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Sending method:

```
@POST
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/files/upload")
@Secured(value = "ROLE_ADMIN")
public String importFile(@RequestParam("filename") MultipartFile mFile, Model model, Locale locale) throws IOException {

    LOG.debug("**** WyWOŁANO > importFile(" + mFile + ")");

    if (!mFile.isEmpty()) {
        if (!validateFile(mFile)) {
            model.addAttribute("message", messageSource.getMessage("file.afterEdit.chosenInCorect", null, locale));
        } else {
            try {
                String fileName = mFile.getOriginalFilename();
                String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                String keyName = uuid.toString() + "." + fileExtension;
                String bucketName = "myspring";

                byte[] bytes = mFile.getBytes();
                ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
                metaData.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, inputStream, metaData);

                AmazonS3 s3client = getAccountClient();
                s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);

                argoFileService.addFile(mFile, keyName);
                model.addAttribute("message", messageSource.getMessage("file.afterEdit.chosenCorect", null, locale));

                LOG.debug("**** WyWOŁANO > importFile(" + mFile + "). Plik dodany do bazy.");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                LOG.error("**** WyWOŁANO > importFile(" + mFile + "). Plik nie został dodany. " +e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }else{
        model.addAttribute("message", messageSource.getMessage("file.noFile", null, locale));
    }
    return "admin/afterUpload";
}

public AmazonS3 getAccountClient() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            "accesskey",
            "secretKey");

    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1)
            .build();

    return s3client;
}
```

Jsp blok:

```
<sf:form id="uploadForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/files/upload"
         method="POST" modelAttribute="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename"/>
    <input type="submit" value="<s:message code="button.upload"/>"/>
</sf:form>
```

Comment: some code would be great, as the path is weird... 
you have tomcat twice, something there doesn't looks ok
/tmp/tomcat.16714439602680400389.5000/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT

Comment: Roie Beck, I added some code, but I don't know where to find bugs. Everything works locally, also the application running on Elastic Beanstalk reads and allows you to download data.

Comment: so maybe the problem is with the security group of the bean, after all in the end it send a file using a port,
maybe the security group is locked for outgoing tcp on that port

Comment: have you solved this problem?